# Trying to test an HTML file in IE7. "$" is undefined error for javascript section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have an all inclusive html file that grabs weather.

When I go to open it in IE7 (to check it), I get an error saying '$' is undefined.

> Line: 136
>
> Char: 9
>
> Error: '$' is undefined.

The actual line is $.ajax and it the start of my javascript function.

Comment: Have you included jquery.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ is defined by jQuery, which you probably haven't referenced. A simple way to get it is to add one of the CDN urls to your template HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

The code you've pasted into your HTML relies on jQuery. The $ is a short-hand reference to the jQuery object. Removing the $s isn't an option. The code won't work at all if you don't include jQuery

Comment: That seemed to work. I grabbed the html file from a folder of a website I work for to test it in IE7. I must have missed a folder with important information through.

Answer (score 1):

Code requires a jQuery to be included in it !